# How do I find the database ID of an inline Notion database

Tags: notion-api

My Notion workspace has, amongst others, a page that contains multiple blocks of various types.  One of these blocks is an **inline** database.  I am trying to access this **inline** database through the Notion API.

I can access databases that are not inline, i.e. the whole page.  However, I don't know how to find the database ID for an **inline** database.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the database id from the link to the database view.  This can be done by clicking the three dots next to the database name or on top next to the New button.
[database view link example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgw5v.png)

you get something like https://www.notion.so/database-id?v=view-id

Comment: Thank you, I thought this was the answer but I still cannot extract my inline database. I must be having another problem.  Thank you for responding to my question.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: I found my problem.  The database I was trying to find was a LINKED database.  However, the search query only returns ORIGINAL database objects because linked database objects are duplicates.  Once I shared the page that contained the original database object the search query had no problem finding it.

Answer (score 0):

My original problem was that I couldn't find the database ID for an INLINE Notion database.

ANSWER: As shown in [@salim-khatib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73083935/5458361)'s answer in the text above.

Although I now had the database ID I still couldn't access the database (object not found). So I decided to use the Notion Search API.  With this API I still couldn't find the database object I was looking for.

After a lot of searching I finally figured out what I had done wrong:

According to the Notion documentation on the Search API: [Notion Search API](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-search), it is very clear that the Search API only returns ORIGINAL database objects and not LINKED database objects as these would be duplicates.  This was my problem, I had linked to a database object that was on a page that I had not shared with my integration.  Once I did the Share the database could be found without a problem.